# Match a tuple of unknown size in scala

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, tuples

Is there way to partially match a `tuple` without having to specify the size? For example, if I had a tuple

```
val v = ( "Dr", "John","H", "Watson")
```

I'd like to be able to do something like :

```
v match { 
   case ( "Dr", : _*) => "What's up, Doc?"
   case ( "Mr", name,   :_*) =>  s"Welcome, Mr. ${name}"
   case _ => "Have we met?"
}
```

This doesn't compile, `:_*` normally means an undetermined number of parameters, but can't be used in this case apparently. The idea would be to be able to use this matcher for any tuple bigger than 2. 
I know i can do it converting `v` to a `List` (for example) first, just want to know if it's possible to do it with a `tuple`.

**EDIT**: the most information I found on the web is [this discussion](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/5801), which dates back to scala 2.8, so I'm gonna with the 'No, you can't' answer.

Comment: As far as I know, there's no way, because tuples of different size are different types. But it can be done with macros - the goal is to generate code that will match all possible sizes. Or as you suggested, define implicit conversions to `Seq[Any]`. This is dirty solution too, and you'd better ask yourself, are the tuples the right type to use in your problem? Maybe they're not.

Comment: @SargeBorsch but they all extend Product ;-)

Comment: @om-nom-nom Yes, it's true, but if you have type Product, you don't know types of its elements and thus lose typesafe access to its data (you need to manually check/cast types of its elements)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Tuples are structures for heterogeneous types. As such, they implement the `productIterator` trait, so you could do:

```
v.productIterator.toList match { 
  case "Dr" :: _ => "What's up, Doc?"
  case "Mr" :: name :: _ =>  s"Welcome, Mr. ${name}"
  case _ => "Have we met?"
}
```

But your example really looks like you want a `Seq[String]` straight away. Is there any reason for wishing to use tuples?

Comment: As stated in the question, I just want to know if it's possible, there's no special reason to use tuples. I actually don't need to do this at all, just being curious :D

Comment: So the short answer is "no", tuples of different arities share nothing among them except providing an `Iterator[Any]`.

Answer (score 10):

This can be done using [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless)'s conversions from tuples to `HLists`,

```
scala> import shapeless._
import shapeless._

scala> import Tuples._
import Tuples._

scala> val v = ( "Dr", "John","H", "Watson")
v: (String, String, String, String) = (Dr,John,H,Watson)

scala> v.hlisted match {
     |   case "Dr" :: _ => "What's up Doc?"
     |   case "Mr" :: name :: _ => s"Welcome, Mr. ${name}"
     |   case _ => "Have we met?"
     | }
res0: String = What's up Doc?
```

Although it's not visible in the above example, note that where possible full static type information is maintained for the names bound in the case clauses, for example,

```
scala> (23, "foo", true).hlisted match {
     |   case i :: s :: b :: HNil => if(b) i+s.length else 0
     |   case _ => -1
     | }
res1: Int = 26
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
case tuple:Product => {
    tuple.productIterator.toList match {
        case (head::rest) => ...

    }
}
```